# OneToMany relationship with checkboxes as choices in a form using custom FormType

Tags: symfony, checkbox, symfony-forms, formbuilder

I have a model CostTypeConnection which has an one to many relation to DepartmentConnection.

I want, that the DepartmentConnection is displayed as checkboxes.

My `CostTypeConnection Class` has a variable `$costType`, which is an `Entity CostType`, that has a `$name` varaible in it.

My `DepartmentConnection Class` has a variable `$department`, which is an `Entity Department`, that has also a `$name` variable.

My CostTypeFormType:

```
  ....    
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('costType', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'costType'
            ))
            ->add('departmentConnections', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new DepartmentConnectionType(),
                'allow_add'    => false,
                'label' => false,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'options' => array('label' => false),

            ))
        ;
    } ...
```

My DepartmentConnection:

```
...
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('department', 'text', array(
                'label' => false
            ))
        ;
    }...
```

So it is not possible to define a checkbox-Type in my Formbuilder for department, because it is an entity and not a variable. Has someone an idea what I can do? This doesnt work in my DepartmentConnectionType Class:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('department', 'choice', array(
                'label' => false
            ))
        ;
    }
```

It finishs with the error:

```
The value of type "object" cannot be converted to a valid array key
```

THANKS FOR ANY HELP!!!

Comment: Typically you would use a data transformer to transform between a department name and a department object.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

Answer (score -1):

Note : recommended minimum version symfony 2.7

You should use \Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType in your form.

see http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/choice.html
and http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Here's an example :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('costType', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Cost type :' // -> <label class="required">Cost type :</label><input value="<?php echo $costTypeConnection->getCostType(); ?> required>
        ))
        ->add('departmentConnections', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'Acme\Bundle\Entity\DepartmentConnection',
            // before 2.7 use 'property' instead of 'choice_label'
            'choice_label' => 'type', // equals $costTypeConnections->getDepartmentConnexion()->getType();
            'label' => 'Department connexion :',
            'expanded' => true, // will output a set of inputs instead of a select tag
            'multiple' => true, // will output checkboxes instead of radio buttons
            'required' => true, // unused as multiple is true
        ))
    ;
} ...
```

would output :

```
<div id="form_cost_type_connexion_department_connections">
    Department connexion :
    <input type="checkbox" value="on" ... <label>$costTypeConnections->getDepartmentConnections()->getType()
    ...
```

Comment: But the name variable is in Department class, not in departmentConnection class

Comment: What is the relationship with your example, it seems you don't use this class in your OP ?

Comment: new answer that should fix your issue @Zwen2012